# Something faster than GetSystemTime?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winapi

I'm writing a DDE logging applet in visual c++ that logs several hundred events per minute and I need a faster way to keep time than calling GetSystemTime in winapi. Do you have any ideas?

(asking this because in testing under load, all exceptions were caused by a call to getsystemtime)

Comment: faster then a few microseconds?  Have you benchmarked?

Comment: Are you *sure* (as in "yes, I have profiled it") that it is the `GetSystemTime` call that is your bottle neck? Several hundred per minute means a handful or two per second, which translated to a virtual eternity of time between the calls. I am quite convinced your problem is not the fact that you call `GetSystemTime`.

Comment: *Exceptions* caused by getSystemTime() ?

Comment: there is no way that GetSystemTime is slower than IO. Be skeptical, confirm that before you try to fix it.

Comment: Apparently it did. Consider that I am also calling getsystemdateformat and getsystemtimeformat... maybe a hundred times in 2 seconds.

Comment: Why did somebody vote to close?

Comment: BTW, are you sure that such exceptions were caused by GetSystemTime? Have you tried to set the debugger to break on first-chance exceptions and see (1) what type of exceptions they are and (2) if they really come from GetSystemTime?

Comment: Why are you calling `GetSystemDateFormat` and `GetSystemTimeFormat` more than once? They're unlikely to change. Also, the only time `GetSystemTime` should throw exceptions is if you pass a null pointer to it - check your code for bugs. It's unlikely that GST is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Getting time is expensive and unfortunately there is no other way. Just be sure that for every log entry you just call it once, store locally and reuse the retrieved timestamp (insetad of calling GST again)

Comment: Matteo, i got read violations in various places under heavy load -- ill take a screenshot when it happens again, but im done with this for the day. By the way, this question has some relevant info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868642/100-khz-timer-frequency-in-windows-xp/1868715#1868715

Comment: Update: it was indeed GetTimeFormatA and not GetSystemTime failing -- my bad. will be caching output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly crazy thought: do you definately need an accurate timestamp? Suppose you only got the system time say every 10th call - how bad would that be?

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this as workaround and should have thought of it myself.. However I would like to have some very fine-grained time reporting; i was loking for a way to get a tick count without calling the API, or milliseconds, or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [mostly undocumented](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234735) struct named [USER_SHARED_DATA](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/KUSER_SHARED_DATA.html) at a high usermode readable address that contains the time and other global things, but GetSystemTime just extracts the time from there and calls RtlTimeToTimeFields so there is not much you can gain by using the struct directly.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments; calling `GetSystemDateFormat` and `GetSystemTimeFormat` *each time* will be a waste of time. These are not likely to change, so those values could easily be cached for improved performance. I would imagine (without having actually tested it) that these two calls are far more time-consuming than a call to `GetSystemTime`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, find out why your code is throwing exceptions (assuming you have described it correctly: i.e. a real exception has been thrown, and the app descends down into kernel mode - which is really slow btw.)

then you will most likely solve any performance bottleneck.

Chris J.

Answer (score 0):

First, The fastest way I could think is using RDTSC instruction. RDTSC is an Intel time-stamp counter instruction with a nanosecond precision. Use it as a combination with CPUID instruction. To use those instructions properly, you can read "[Using the RDTSC Instruction for Performance Monitoring](http://www.ccsl.carleton.ca/~jamuir/rdtscpm1.pdf)", then you can convert the nanoseconds to seconds for your purpose.

Second, consider using QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerformanceCounter().

Third, not the fastest but much faster than the standard GetSystemTime(), that is, using timeGetTime().